# External call on AWS lambda function in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Let's say I have a C# Web API which I have deployed as an AWS Lambda function via instructions here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploy-an-existing-asp-net-core-web-api-to-aws-lambda/

Now I can call my API as follows:
https://someaddress.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/test/get

Works great!

However, in order to interact with the database, I need to have my lambda function access AWS RDS. To make this happen, I apparently need the lambda function and database to be in the same VPC. I have done this, opened the db and lambda security groups fully to all traffic (just to get it working), and added NAT to the VPC subnet.

Now I can no longer call my function. 
{"message": "Endpoint request timed out"}

I assume the API gateway is no longer able to direct traffic to my lambda function. Why? How do I fix this?

Comment: "and added NAT to the VPC subnet."

Is it your custom VPC? Are the subnets public? ie have an internet Gateway attached to the route tables associated with the subnets. NAT is for egress.

Comment: I would guess that your Lambda function is being invoked (check CloudWatch Logs to be sure) but its RDS interaction is timing out because your connectivity is setup incorrectly. BTW if the Lambda function and RDS DB are in the same VPC then there's no need for NAT, you just need to setup security groups (and DB credentials) correctly.

Comment: Lambda function and RDS are in the same VPC, so removed NAT. Database connectivity now working!

On a related note, let's suppose I wanted the lambda function to be able to access some external resource too (perhaps some public API). What would I need to configure to allow that?